# Catch USSD Codes

Tags: ussd

I need some help to figure out a way to catch which USSD codes are executing in my phone. This is for a little project I'm working on, to simplify an app that my cell carrier provides, but I don't have any idea of what codes are executing some times, couse there are not documentation about it. I'm expecting something like a sniffer or similar, but I'm open to suggestions. My handset is a Xiaomi Redmi Note 5, just in case somebody knows a way to achieve what I'm looking for doing a trick in system settings or something hidden in the OS.

Comment: [Notification history](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) logs USSD. Try that

Comment: Sorry but this is not the behavior I was looking for. I don't need the USSD message itselft, but the code executed to get this message, i.e. if the app executes *1234# and I get the answer "Hello user", I want to know that the code used was  *1234#, not the message returned